# Setting ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true in .zshrc doesn't work

Tags: homebrew, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I need to disable the zsh's COMPFIX process to suppress the following warning I see every time I open a terminal window:

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories and files, run compaudit for list.
```

The cause of the warning is not the issue here; I have two admin users on the same Macbook who both need to use homebrew. When files in /usr/local have group read/write privileges rather than single user privileges, the COMPFIX process flags them as insecure.

Other solutions suggest adding `ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true` to the top of my `.zshrc` file. I have done this and I still see the error. There are multiple `.zshrc`-like files in my home directory, including `.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` and `.zshrc~`, and have tried adding `ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX=true` to each of these too, without success.

How can I successfully turn off this warning?

Answer (score 34):

Try to add it at the beginning of the .zshrc file, 
before sourcing oh-my-zsh

and put it in quotes like: ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure to `ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"` on the first line of your `.zshrc` file

Comment: Quotes do not matter in strings without space.

Answer (score 6):

You likley just need to place true in quotes like so:
`ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"`

Then reload your zsh settings with `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: I have tried both with and without quotations around 'true', but it hasn't worked yet.

Comment: Quotes don't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true" to my z.sh file (with or without quotes worked). Adding it to .zshrc file gave me an error message.